# UAV simulation of obstacle avoidance in Gazebo?

Tags: simulation, path-planning, uav

I would like to simulate some 3D path planning capabilities of an UAV in Gazebo. So Firstly, I download a point cloud of an outdoor area with obstacles. I can find any in internet.Than Load the point cloud to Gazebo. After that,convert point cloud to 3D model (something like this [point cloud convert](https://gazebosim.org/api/gazebo/3.3/pointcloud.html)). So for this purpose I can use any type of UAV available in a standard ROS packages, or e.g. some of the MRS drones[Drones](https://github.com/ctu-mrs).

So my question is how to show 3D path planning capabilities of an UAV: e.g. given a starting location, show how does the trajectory avoids obstacles in the 3D model?

Any help on that?

Comment: Start your node, then open a terminal and type `ros topic list` If you see a topic like /nav_msgs/path then you can just visualize that topic in Gazebo and see the path

Comment: yes .. Any example node in C++ or Python can be find?

Comment: Did you really understand, what I said to do? I never told you to create or implement a C++ or Python node

Comment: well my question is how to do path planning and then visualize it. So will need a node right?

Comment: yes but then which node to start?